# Centos-updates list item with yum

Tags: centos

Can somebody help me? i need to get the available update list on Centos without the header information, and it shoud work on evry Centos version. How can i do that?
PS: I can't use plugins just yum command combined with AWK or anything else

Comment: Does `repoquery` help you do what you want? If not you'll need to figure out what the output from `yum list available` looks like enough to be able to filter only the lines you want.

Answer (score 0):

check if

`yum check-update -q`

or

`yum updateinfo -q`

matches your requirements. You can use these commands to extract the data you want, like `yum check-update -q | cut -d ' ' -f1` to get just a list of the package names with updates.